# How to run Flask route from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am making an image gallery with Flask as backend and JS. Right now I'm stuck trying to make the images open by clicking on the thumbnails. I can pass image variable to Flask using XMLHttpRequest and run Flask function but I don't understand what prevents Flask function from running html template.
For example, Flask can print the right file name, which comes from JS, but can't return template.

JS:

```js
let imageContainers = document.querySelectorAll('#imageContainer')
       imageContainers.forEach(function(item, index) {item.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let imgToFlask = imgList[index];
        request.open('POST', `/image_view/${JSON.stringify(imgToFlask)}`);
        request.send();
       })})
```

Flask:

```py
@app.route('/image_view/<imgToFlask>', methods=['POST'])
def image_view(imgToFlask):
    image = imgToFlask
    print(image) //After this line code execution seems to stop
    return render_template('image_view.html', image=image)
```

What I have in terminal after clicking on the image file:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jul/2023 10:40:59] "POST /image_view/%22489916z_489916S.jpg%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> "489916z_489916S.jpg"

Comment: So the execution just stops, without any errors? What does the function output look like?

Comment: No any error, just print filename in terminal

Comment: So, you send an AJAX request to Flask, which renders an HTML page, and then you do nothing with the returned HTML. What was expected to happen?

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong then? Is the JS getting the wrong output? What does it look like? Or is the JS getting an HTTP error? Maybe you expected the user to be *redirected*?

Comment: I want Flask will render new html page ('image_view.html') with full-screen picture using file name received from JS. And, which is more important I want to understand why my code not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The render_template method only create an HTTP Response containing the desired template. You are not using the response of your XMLHTTPRequest so nothing happens. You could do:

```js
let imageContainers = document.querySelectorAll('#imageContainer')
       imageContainers.forEach(function(item, index) {item.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let imgToFlask = imgList[index];
        window.location.href = `/image_view/${JSON.stringify(imgToFlask)}`;
       })})
```

But then you'd have to change the method of the endpoint to GET.
If you want it to stay POST, you need to do:

```js
let imageContainers = document.querySelectorAll('#imageContainer')
       imageContainers.forEach(function(item, index) {item.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let imgToFlask = imgList[index];
        request.open('POST', `/image_view/${JSON.stringify(imgToFlask)}`);
        request.onload = ()=>{
          page = response.response;
          document.innerHTML = page;
        }
        request.send();
       })})
```

Comment: First (GET) option generates new page with filename on it. But when I try to show the actual image (with full path) it throw 404 NOT FOUND. Second (POST) returns ReferenceError: response is not defined at request.onload.

Comment: I didn't understand the first problem, the second is probably because I wrote response and I think it's probably responseText